# I am not able to retrieve the data from json file into ionic

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

```js
var app = angular.module('Event', ['ionic']);
    app.controller('ExhibitionTabCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("data.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
       $scope.names = response;
      });
    }]);
  $scope.questions = [];
  $http
    .get("data.json")
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.questions = response.data.questions;
    });
}])
```

```html
 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
 <link rel="manifest" href="data.json">
    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <!--<h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>-->
  <button class="button button-small">
   Back
</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="searchForce" style="margin-left:70%;">
      <button ng-if="searchForce.length"
              class="button button-icon ion-android-close input-button"
              ng-click="clearSearch()">
      </button>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ExhibitionTabCtrl">
   <p> sample.date</p>
 
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

 
 
  </body>
</html>
```

[
{
"Date" : "Thursday 16 Mar",
 "Data1" : "Sample Child",
 "Data2" : "Sample Class",
 "Date" : "6:29 pm", 
 "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img2.jpg",
 "text" : "Tiger Tale", 
 "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img5.jpg"
 },
{
"Date" : "Tuesday 14 Mar",
 "Data1" : "Sample Child",
 "Data2" : "Sample Class",
 "Date" : "12:43 pm", 
 "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img6.jpg",
 "text" : "Tiger Tale",
 "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg"
 },
{
"Date" : "Friday 10 Mar",
"Data1" : "Sample Child",
"Data2" : "Sample Class",
"Date" : "12:03 pm",
 "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img1.jpg",
 "text" : "Tiger Tale",
 "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg"
 }]

Answer (score 0):

Try this after inserting data.json into www folder.It works perfectly.You can read data from data.json file.

```js
var app = angular.module('Event', ['ionic']);
    app.controller('ExhibitionTabCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
     $http.get("data.json")
      .success(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response;
      });
}])
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
 <link rel="manifest" href="data.json">
    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <!--<h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>-->
  <button class="button button-small">
   Back
</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="searchForce" style="margin-left:70%;">
      <button ng-if="searchForce.length"
              class="button button-icon ion-android-close input-button"
              ng-click="clearSearch()">
      </button>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ExhibitionTabCtrl">
   <p ng-repeat="number in names">{{number.Data1}}</p>
 
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

 
 
  </body>
</html>
```